# Netifaces gives KeyError: 2 while running from cron

Tags: networking, command-line, scripts, python, cron

I want to schedule a cron job for running a server client application during startup. What I did is `crontab -e` and then put the following line `@reboot cd path/to/folder && /usr/bin/sh /home/Folder1/execute.sh`. The contents of the `execute.sh` file are :

```
. ./venv/bin/activate
python main.py
```

The folder contains the `sh` file, `main.py`and the `.env` file which stores the `NETWORK_MODE`. The cron job does initiate at startup. However I am facing a netifaces module error in the following lines from `main.py` where I obtain the ip.

```
import netifaces as ni
ip = ni.ifaddresses(os.environ.get("NETWORK_MODE", "eth0"))[ni.AF_INET][0]['addr']
```

The error is `keyError:2`
I thought may be it executes before the internet turns on and in that case i changed my crontab entry as

```
@reboot sleep 120 && cd path/to/folder && /usr/bin/sh /home/Folder1/execute.sh
```

Still the error persists. What can possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not related to `cron`.

Assuming `python3`:

You need to `import os` as well like so:

```py
import os
import netifaces as ni

ip = ni.ifaddresses(os.environ.get("NETWORK_MODE", "eth0"))[ni.AF_INET][0]['addr']
```

As a styling note [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#:%7E:text=spaces%20for%20indentation.-,Maximum%20Line%20Length,be%20limited%20to%2072%20characters.) sets the maximum length of a line of code to  79 characters ... so to comply to that, I would suggest:

```py
import os
import netifaces as ni

oi = os.environ.get("NETWORK_MODE", "eth0")
ip = ni.ifaddresses(oi)[ni.AF_INET][0]['addr']
```

but, you don't need all that ... all you need is:

```py
import netifaces as ni

ip = ni.ifaddresses('eth0')[ni.AF_INET][0]['addr']
```

and make sure you specify a valid interface name.

The error itself:

```
KeyError: 2
```

however, means you ar trying to access a `2` key in a a dictionary that doesn't contain the key ... try this for an example:

```py
my_dict = {1: ['a', 'b'], 3: ['e', 'f']}

print(my_dict[2])
```

That will result in `KeyError: 2` because, you tried to access a `2` key in a dictionary that doesn't contain it.

and in your case, it means that your interface does not have an IP4 address assigned to it i.e. not connected ... `ni.ifaddresses('eth0')[ni.AF_INET]` will have a key value of `2` when the interface is connected ... i.e. if the interface is connected, then the second key will contain IP4 but, if the interface is not connected, then there will be no IP4 entry/item and no `2` key ... hence the error message you get ... take a look at what the following code prints when `eth0` is connected, then disconnect it and run the code again to compare the output to understand:

```py
import netifaces as ni

eth0 = ni.ifaddresses('eth0')
print(eth0)
```

Comment: `os` and `netifaces` modules are already imported inside the `main.py` but still getting error.

Comment: @mrin9san I explained as much as I could ... your script is fine ... the cron job is running ... no problems seem present here ... the issue is that your specified interface is down at the time the script runs

Comment: Thanks for your comments..yeah..you are right probably something does not start up right when I run it startup..i suspect its my internet connection